# IIS 7.5 AutoStart

Tags: iis-7.5

I have the IIS 7.5 installed on the server, but I can't find the configurations about autostart. When I try to edit the IISs config file the application pool that I had edited doesn't start.

Serching the internet I had read about the Windows Server AppFabric, do I have to install this to use the autostart?

And, to complete the mess, I couldn't complete the instalation of the AppFabric. I got the error: "Setup.exe has stopped working", with no clear reason.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Ps.: I met all the requirements, like windows 7 and such.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has the same problem:

After formatting my pc and reinstalling everything, I could install the AppFabric.
Then the necessary options for the use of AutoStart appeared.